# First Query only - ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql

Every time I connect to my MySQL db via command line and run any query, I get an `ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away` and a really slow query run time.

It happens again when I run another query after `connect timeout` time has exceeded.

Is it by design or some issue with the DB?

My concern is that anyone connecting to DB via PHP application would get a slow first response which is not ideal for performance reasons.

Cheers

Comment: Try to execute `SELECT VERSION();` as the most first query - does it will produce the timeout?

Comment: No it doesnt give the error.

Comment: But the next query produces the timeout again? If so then it is possible that the server needs in much time for to cache the data (tables, indices), in this case look at server's disk subsystem, maybe it is slow. Also it is possible that the server have no enough RAM.

Comment: Sorry tried it again. As long as any query is 10 second apart (timeout value), it gives the error. No issues with RAM or underlying disk. 64G RAM on AWS IO2 EBS.